# How to make filtered items to displayed in listview using search functionality(android)

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, widget

I have a edittext, search button and listview in my activity, based on the keyword given in the edittext box all the related items should be displayed in the listview, now i'm able to get the those related items in toast, that is all the related items gets poped up one by one in toast and gets diappeared, but i want it be in displayed in listview, how will i make it?
     here's my code

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
JSONArray posts;

 //ArrayList thats going to hold the search results
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResults;
  LayoutInflater inflater;
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.example.com/ads/?json=get_recent_posts";

static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText searchBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    final ListView  list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //get the LayoutInflater for inflating the customomView
     //this will be used in the custom adapter
     inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Creating JSON Parser instance
                final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                     posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url = null;
                    String slug = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
                }   
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              //searchResults=OriginalValues initially
                searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(songsList);
         // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);    
             list.setAdapter(adapter);

             searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //get the text in the EditText
                   String searchString=searchBox.getText().toString();
                   int textLength=searchString.length();

                          //clear the initial data set
                   searchResults.clear();

                   for(int i=0;i<songsList.size();i++)
                   {
                  String playerName=songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();

                  if(textLength<=playerName.length()){

                  //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                    if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength)))
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),playerName,1).show();
                    searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));
                  }
                   }

                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                     int after) {

                   }

                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                   }
                  });


    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);

            Intent in = new Intent(Home.this, Singlemenuitem.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
            in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, map.get(KEY_DATE));                         
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, map.get(KEY_NAME));
            in.putExtra(KEY_CONTENT, map.get(KEY_CONTENT));
            in.putExtra(KEY_URL, map.get(KEY_URL));

            startActivity(in);
        }                
    });   

}
```

Comment: please elaborate about the problem you are facing with this code.

Comment: getting error in the place of filter public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                   Home.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);

               }
           }); as The method getFilter() is undefined for the type LazyAdapter @SahilMahajanMj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i replaced the below code so got the my search function working:)

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //get the text in the EditText
                    searchString=searchBox.getText().toString();
                    textLength=searchString.length();
                   searchResults.clear();

                   for(int i=0;i<songsList.size();i++)
                   {
                   playerName=songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();
                  System.out.println("player name "+playerName);
                  if(textLength<=playerName.length()){
                  //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                    if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength))){
                    searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));
                    System.out.println("the array list is "+songsList.get(i));
                    adapter=new LazyAdapter(Home.this, searchResults);   

                     list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                      }


                   }
                   if(searchResults.isEmpty()){
                       Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                  "No Items Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                                  toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                                  toast.show();
                   }
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                     int after) {
                 System.out.println("before changed");

                   }

                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                                               System.out.println("after changed");
                   }
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made the filtering last really messy. Try the code that is working for me.

First set the filteration true for the list,

```
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Then use the edit text for filteration as follows,

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            MyActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);

        }
    });
```

Use this code and check if it works or not.

Comment: public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                   Home.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);

               } getting error in the place of Fileter as The method getFilter() is undefined for the type LazyAdapter